# Struts2 application giving blank pages while browsing 

Tags: java, firefox, tomcat, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have struts2 application with struts2 version 2.0, There is no error on server side or client side but frequently its **showing blank pages while browsing**. It seems like browser could not render the html page. These blank pages are not shown on specific pages but randomly shown on different pages.

I have been told to fix problem but could not guess where the problem is. I tried disabling dev mode using `struts.xml` tag

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
```

Also I tried to host website on different machine but it did not solved problem, 
Can somebody please help me solve problem,

I am using apache tomcat version 6.26

EDIT:
No Tpmcat logs are coming with respect to current problem, When checked the source its not blank. I am using Firefox 3.6.4, , How can I solve this problem ? Can it be solved

Comment: Is the generated HTML source also blank? Rightclick and view source. Further, are you **100% sure** that nothing in server logs is found? There's more than one file where a server will log to. Start with `domainname.yyyy-MM-dd.log` in `Tomcat/logs`. If there's really nothing in logs, then it would require *much more* time to nail this down.

Comment: Source is not blank coming when I view the source by right clicking it. No logs are coming with respect to current problem,

Comment: If the source isn't blank, then we'll need some details about what it is you're seeing in "View Source" and what's different compared to a page that *does* show something in the browser.  There are a surprisingly large number of ways to create a blank-looking page in HTML.  :)

Comment: @ZoogieZork: Source is coming as expected when I click on dropdown near back button of browser which shows history of pages and select latest/current page again it shows correctly but not the first time I visit page. I suspect that its the problem of browser but I cannot use different browser as this website is designed for Firefox only and looks differently in other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the webpage source is correctly coming in, this just look like a FireFox specific issue. [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+3+loads+blank+page) also learns me that you're not the only one who encounter this issue. There are several possible client side software based causes for this:

- [Zoom function is conflicting](http://groups.google.com/group/google-reader-troubleshoot/browse_thread/thread/b939785ac6d899bf/d943b293aae474e4?pli=1) (hit `Ctrl+0` to fix)
- [Norton 360 firewall is conflicting](http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?forumId=1&comments_parentId=87058) (disable it to fix)
- [NVIDIA firewall is conflicting](http://www.techsupportforum.com/alternative-computing/mozilla-firefox-browsers/203520-firefox-only-loads-blank-pages.html) (disable it to fix)
- [Realplayer plugin is conflicting](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/545528) (disable it to fix)
- [Flash plugin is conflicting](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=516698) (disable it to fix)
- [There's spyware/adware/virus at your system](http://software.allfaq.org/forums/t/122500.aspx) (scan and clean to fix)

Regardless, best what you can do as quick test is to try a different webbrowser (e.g. [MSIE8](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx), [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) or [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/)) and play/surf the website. Don't worry about layout, it's about functionality now. If it all works flawlessly, then it's certainly a FireFox related issue. Try [creating a new FireFox profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-us/kb/Managing+profiles#Creating_a_profile) and retry. Try disabling all software based firewalls you have at your machine. Try [scanning](http://www.safer-networking.org) your system for spyware. Try testing in other machines as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this website on Google chrome and functions perfectly. I wonder why Firefox goes mad with my website only and not with the others ?

Comment: Maybe because certain plugins got triggered during loading your site and were conflicting?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to put different log messages between the JSP lines and to check till where the code is getting executed properly so that you can pinpoint exactly where the problem is coming.

Comment: It gets executed as I get output in html source